# dual-boot Ubuntu on Windows11

Tags: dual-boot, windows-11

I had dual-boot Ubuntu on Windows11 but I am facing two problems after installation
1)not getting the option of create file
2)not able to do partition of drives

Comment: Have you installed gparted ?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Did you install Ubuntu with wsl  ON Windows or did you install it along side Windows dual boot. Is it installed or are you trying to install Ubuntu? What version of Ubuntu are you using? Details are needed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)